# understanding value on token transfer transaction

Tags: transactions, ether, tokens, erc-20

When a token transfer transaction has an ether price associated with it, is it fair to assume that that transaction used ether to buy the tokens?

For example, [this](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xfc19b0a19a443e4e1544feb0ff35714c24bb5eeaa9852dfc043adb4e8bde7f2a) transacion triggered by account A  transfered 1680 tokens from acc 0x0000...to account A (tokens where minted) and cost 12 ehter. 
Is it fair to say that the value of the token at the time was 12/1680 = 0.0071428571428571  ETH?

Answer (score 1):

The concept of "value" is a rather dodgy one. If you buy a car with X money from a shop, its value drops dramatically after the first minute when you drive it out of the shop as it becomes a used car.

I would argue it's impossible to determine the *value* of a token. But the *price* of a token is a bit easier though it may go wrong as well.

If you send a transaction with 10 Ethers to a contract and you get X tokens back you might claim that you now know the price of the tokens. Well, what if the crowdsale contract for example gives you the same amount of tokens after a month? Or returns some of your Ethers after a while? It may be impossible to know what the real price is.

But, in typical scenarios you can make an educated guess that if you send X Ethers and get Y tokens back the actual price at that moment is known. This is probably the case in at least 95% of crowdsales.

Answer (score 0):

That's right.The price should be 1680/12 = 140 tokens per ETH. thus per token price is 1/140 = 0.0071428571428571

Answer (score 0):

Also you can check their price function, they have different rate of price:

```
function calcAmountAt(uint256 _value, uint256 at) public constant returns (uint256) {
        uint rate;

        if(startTime + 2 days >= at) {
            rate = 140;
        } else if(startTime + 7 days >= at) {
            rate = 130;
        } else if(startTime + 14 days >= at) {
            rate = 120;
        } else if(startTime + 21 days >= at) {
            rate = 110;
        } else {
            rate = 105;
        }
        return ((_value * rate) / weiPerToken) / 100;
    }
```